# Count diff with datetimes and today and group it in one month frequency using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following format of data in a csv:

```
1,2015-02-01
```

The format is

```
<internal_id>,<datetime>
```

I want to ignore the internal id, and use the datetime (if posible even not read it from the csv to save memory).

And what I want is to plot a histogram of the difference in months of the dates in the file and today, each bar of the histogram being a month.

The process in pseudo-code is:
1) Calculate de difference in month of each row in the file and today
2) Accumulate that differences in buckets of one month
3) Plot in a histogram or something similar

For now I have made this code in a **jupyter notebook** with **python3**:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

% matplotlib notebook

text = """1,2015-01-01
1,2015-02-01
1,2015-02-01
1,2015-03-01
1,2015-03-01
1,2015-03-01
1,2015-04-01
1,2015-04-01
1,2015-04-01
1,2015-04-01"""

plt.subplots()
def diff(row_date):
    today = datetime.now()
    return (today.year - row_date.year) * 12 + (today.month - row_date.month)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), usecols=[1], header=None, names=['date'], parse_dates=['date'])
serie = df.date
serie = serie.apply(diff)
serie.hist()
```

[image: code in jupyter]
[image: Plot result]

Is there a more elegant way to do it using built-in function to group and calculate the difference of time using Pandas? (or faster)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """1,2015-01-18
1,2015-02-10
1,2015-02-15
1,2015-02-20
1,2015-03-01
1,2015-03-02
1,2015-03-03"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), header=None, parse_dates=[1], names=['count', 'Date'], index_col=1)

df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).count().hist()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi piRSquared, thanks for the answer, but the first element of the csv is a id so I cannot use it to count. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeC fixed it.  I replaced `sum` with `count`.  `count` just takes the length of that group.

Comment: Hi again, I think the solution does not do what I whant, solution: http://imgur.com/a/fTt7k   desired: http://imgur.com/a/OQMy4

Comment: @GeorgeC you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  It becomes counter productive when you don't provide what you expect upfront.  Consider reading that document and editing your question.

Comment: Yeap, you are right, there goes a better explanation.